# How to (easily) calculate confidence & prediction intervals AFTER a model selection procedure?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, feature-selection

First of all, this question refers mostly to linear regression. When someone uses a model selection procedure, for example, choosing the optimal dimensionality of the predictor space via best subset regression and the minimization of Mallows' Cp, it is not possible anymore to calculate realistic confidence & prediction intervals in a classic manner, because they do not take the selection procedure into account. In effect the intervals will be to small/overoptimistic.Is there a convenient way to calculate statistical intervals in this sort of situation?

I thought of bootstrapping, but because of the discontinuities in the selected model and the quite erratic fluctuations in point predictions I am not sure if that is really a good idea.

Best would be, if someone knows a tool in R for coping with this kind of situation.

Comment: It is not easy by any means. You may consider this paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1369836961

Comment: ...and this: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2013.823775 (an open access version can be found)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks. I already read the second one and to be honest - i did not really get his calulations... I was hoping that maybe someone has already implemented his formula in some kind of nice to use R tool or something. But okey maybe this is unrealistic for the moment.